# Laptop doesn't recognize Second monitor

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a problem with my XPS17. It doesn't recognize monitors when connected, but does recognize TVs. I tried plugging monitors to either the HDMI port or the Mini-DVI port, using an adapter. The computer does not respond when the cables are plugged into it, no second monitor options appear and forced detection (using the nVidia panel) doesn't work either.

Drivers are updated, BIOS is updated. TV works great when connected to my computer and I have no problem with that. I tested 2 monitors with different cables but non of them work.

Does anyone know anything that might solve this? I use Windows 8.

Kind regards

Comment: Have you tried connecting your monitors on another computer to check that they are operating normaly ?

Comment: Yup I did... Also checked the HDMI cable, and the adapter is working as well.

Comment: How are you connecting to the TV? Is your cable setup any different with second monitor vs TV?

Comment: To connect  to my tv I use a Standard HDMI kabel and that works Just fine. To connect to my monitor I use the same HDMI kabel, but at the and I place an HDMI to dvi converter